# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'AppRoutes'

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular9

I am trying to achieve my angular application route to split in to 3 clear part.

1. App-Router Module => let it load the app scope module routes. ( at present i have 1 scope as "setup-config )
2. let Scope-Module take care of feature modules. ( at present i have 2 feature modules )
3. let the feature module take care of it's own feature components.

the reason to clarity and rescablility i am trying to achieve this. but getting an error as `"Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'AppRoutes'.`"

Any one help me to sort this issue? if the way what i try is wrong, can any one please show me the correct way to achieve this?

[Here is the live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scope-router?file=src/app/setup-config/setup-config.routes.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `AppRoutes` declared twice in your file. You should probably name one `appRoutes`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  path:"",
  pathMatch:"full",
  loadChildren:() => import('./setup-config/setup-config.module').then(m => m.ScopeModule)
}]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ScopeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { 
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: []
})
export class AppRoutes {}
```

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scope-router-ur3rzt?file=src/app/app.routes.ts)

[working one with routing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scope-router-yrzcj5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsetup-config%2Fsetup-config.routes.ts)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I create 2 links in app.component.html. but by clicking them not working. can you help here?

Comment: @3gwebtrain there is too much wrong. Couple things, you can only use `forRoot` from the router once. Use `forChild` for features. You cannot import the `BrowserModule` in multiple modules, use `CommonModule`. Your feature modules need a router config as well and a component it 'lands' on. You should not use `pathMatch` for routes, only when redirecting. You should not import lazy loaded modules in other modules, these should only be loaded through the router

Comment: @3gwebtrain I've had to change a lot lot.. Too much to add as an answer, but i did post a working example with routing

Answer (score 1):

in your `app.routes.ts` file, you have `AppRoutes` as the name of your `Routes` array **and the name of your class in the same file**. Consider renaming the name of the `Routes` array.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ScopeModule } from './setup-config/setup-config.module';

const AppRoutes: Routes = [ // This is called AppRoutes

 {
    path:"",
    pathMatch:"full",
    loadChildren:() => import('./setup-config/setup-config.module').then(m => m.ScopeModule)
  }

]

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ScopeModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { 
          scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
          useHash: true
        })
    ],
    exports: []
})
export class AppRoutes { } // This is **also** called AppRoutes
```

Comment: I added 2 hyperlink for 2 features. but not working. can you have a look?\